# Python - Two (slightly different) JSON arrays Comparison

Tags: python, python-2.7

i need to compare the two JSON arrays below, and end up with the below `emails_new` result ... The stick in the mud I'm finding is one of the arrays has an extra key/value pair, which I need in the updated array. So struggling to match.

Essentially; *'if any email(s) in emails_exist appear in emails_all, don't include them as part of emails_new'*

#### Existing Arrays

```
emails_all = [{'email': 'new@email.com', 'first_name': 'New Name'}, {'email': 'exists@email.com', 'first_name': 'Exists Name'}]

emails_exist = [{'email': 'exists@email.com'}]
```

Removing all of the `emails_exist` values from the `emails_all`, I only want to build a list to show the email/first_name of the emails that do not appear in `emails_exist` ... Similar to the below `emails_new`

#### Output

```
emails_new = [{'email': 'new@email.com', 'first_name': 'New'}]
```

Possibly worthy of note: these JSON arrays may have up to 100 items in each.

Comment: as far as I can tell, your question has nothing to do with JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a simple helper function

```
def contains(emails, email):                      
    for contained_email in emails:                   
        if email["email"] == contained_email["email"]: 
            return True                                 
    return False                                    

emails_new = [email for email in emails_all if not contains(emails_exist, email)]
```

Comment: Very clever @peter , and for my lack of sleep brain, this 'simple helper' function is liquid Adderall, thanks. One thing, the resulting array still need to have the `first_name` key/value ... Currently it spits out the `[{'email': 'new@email.com'},]` only. Possible?

Comment: @Danny Are you sure? The new array contains only entries from `emails_all` wihtout modifying them in any way. They should still contain the first_name. It just filters out the entries that return True using the `contains` function.

Comment: Ugh, apologies, I'm on no sleep ... I'd removed the `ProjectionExpression` from the DDB call while testing, what a 15 years in the business, amateur. Thanks Peter, this works perfectly. I do not

Answer (score 0):

**@Danny**, you can also get the expected output with just 1 line of code using Python's **list comprehension**, **map()**, **filter()**, **lambda function** etc. as the below code examples shows.

Please comment if you face any problem while reading & understanding my code.

> Check [Lambda, filter(), map()](https://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php) and [List comprehension](https://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php). It's really good to use these concepts in programming.

### 1 line code

```
emails_new = list(filter(lambda email_all_dict: True if sum(list(map(lambda email_exist_dict: True if email_exist_dict["email"] == email_all_dict['email'] else False, emails_exist))) == 0 else False, emails_all))
```

Now have a look at the below code examples one by one.

### Example 1

```
emails_all = [{'email': 'new@email.com', 'first_name': 'New Name'}, {'email': 'exists@email.com', 'first_name': 'Exists Name'}]

emails_exist = [{'email': 'exists@email.com'}]

emails_new = list(filter(lambda email_all_dict: True if sum(list(map(lambda email_exist_dict: True if email_exist_dict["email"] == email_all_dict['email'] else False, emails_exist))) == 0 else False, emails_all))

print(emails_new)

# [{'first_name': 'New Name', 'email': 'new@email.com'}]
```

### Example 2

```
emails_all = [
        {'email': 'new1@email.com', 'first_name': 'New Name1'}, 
        {'email': 'exists1@email.com', 'first_name': 'Exists Name1'},
        {'email': 'exists2@email.com', 'first_name': 'Exists Name2'},
        {'email': 'exists5@email.com', 'first_name': 'Exists Name5'},
        {'email': 'exists6@email.com', 'first_name': 'Exists Name6'},
        {'email': 'new9@email.com', 'first_name': 'New Name9'}, 
        {'email': 'exists7@email.com', 'first_name': 'Exists Name7'},
        {'email': 'exists8@email.com', 'first_name': 'Exists Name8'},
        {'email': 'exists4@email.com', 'first_name': 'Exists Name4'},
        {'email': 'new4@email.com', 'first_name': 'New Name4'}, 
        {'email': 'new2@email.com', 'first_name': 'New Name2'}, 
        {'email': 'exists3@email.com', 'first_name': 'Exists Name3'}
]

emails_exist = [
        {'email': 'exists@email.com'},    # Does not exist
        {'email': 'exists7@email.com', 'first_name': 'Exists Name7'},
        {'email': 'exists8@email.com', 'first_name': 'Exists Name8'},
        {'email': 'exists4@email.com', 'first_name': 'Exists Name4'}
]

emails_new2 = list(filter(lambda email_all_dict: True if sum(list(map(lambda email_exist_dict: True if email_exist_dict["email"] == email_all_dict['email'] else False, emails_exist))) == 0 else False, emails_all))

# Pretty printing list
print(json.dumps(emails_new2, indent=4))

"""
[
    {
        "first_name": "New Name1",
        "email": "new1@email.com"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Exists Name1",
        "email": "exists1@email.com"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Exists Name2",
        "email": "exists2@email.com"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Exists Name5",
        "email": "exists5@email.com"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Exists Name6",
        "email": "exists6@email.com"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "New Name9",
        "email": "new9@email.com"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "New Name4",
        "email": "new4@email.com"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "New Name2",
        "email": "new2@email.com"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Exists Name3",
        "email": "exists3@email.com"
    }
]
"""
```